# Time stamp doesn't reset when panning or zooming

Tags: matlab, timestamp, matlab-figure

So one thing that bothers me is about MATLAB figures is that timestamps are a challenge to render properly.

For instance

```
time = now:1/24/3600:now+1;
xval  = sin((time-time(1)).^2*2*pi) + cos(2*(time-time(1)).^4*2*pi);
plot(time, xval)
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', datestr(get(gca,'Xtick'),'HH:MM'));
```

[image]

Now the problem with this is that xlabels will not adjust properly when I pan or zoom:

[image]

Rather what you see is the same tick labels being recycled... This of course come back to the fact that the program does what you tell it to do....

What I have to do is call `set(gca, 'XTickLabel', datestr(get(gca,'Xtick'),'HH:MM'));` again...

But I'm lazy bum and I don't want to do this everytime I pan and zoom. I want it to be programmed in the figure, somehow.

Now figures has this wonderful thing called `WindowButtonMotionFcn`, from which I can call another function:

```
set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @plot_time_change)

function plot_time_change (gcbo, eventdata, handles)  
set(gca,'XTickLabel',datestr(get(gca,'Xtick'),'HH:MM'));
end
```

This works OK, but it is not visually elegant, especially given that it doesn't get called when I zoom.

So the question is: are there better solutions that I'm missing out on?

Answer (score 0):

Set the post call back action for zoom to your plot_time_change function

```
set(zoom(gca),'ActionPostCallback',@plot_time_change)
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940561/does-matlab-execute-a-callback-when-a-plot-is-zoomed-resized-redrawn) previous question for more